# Trying to connect android app with Webservice

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask, asmx

Good evening, i have being trying to make a code so i can connect my android app with my web service to finally reach a MS database. i have try with async process but i dont succed.

Here is my code:

```
   private Button btnLogin;
   private EditText txtUsername;
   private EditText txtPassword;


   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.login);

       txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePersonName);
       txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePassword); 
       btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

       btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

                  LoginWSsql login = new LoginWSsql();
                  login.execute();
            }
        });
       }

        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

        private class LoginWSsql extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> 
        {
             protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

                   boolean resul = true;

                   final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
                   final String URL="http://192.168.1.104:9090/PruebaAndroid.asmx"; 
                   final String METHOD_NAME = "PruebaAndroid";
                   final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/PruebaAndroid";

                   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                   request.addProperty("", txtUsername.getText().toString()); 

                   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
                            new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                    envelope.dotNet = true; 

                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    try
                    {
                        transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                        SoapPrimitive resultado_xml =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                        String res = resultado_xml.toString();

                        if(res.equals("hola madlito"))
                                {
                            resul = false;
                                }
                    }
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            resul = false;
                        }  

                        return resul;


             }  

             protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

                    if (result)
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "conectado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Falla",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                }

        }
}
```

The problems is that when i do click on the button the program immediately crushes and throw me this message:

Unfortunately, SecurityAPP has stopped.

Can someone please help me!!!!!

Comment: Post the error log